# Yii2 Post to controller and get back data

Tags: yii2

This is my code in view.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'projectTitle')->dropDownList($fullprojectlist, [
'prompt'=>'-Choose a Course-',
'id' => 'projectList',
'type'=> 'POST',
'onchange'=>' var value = $("#projectList :selected").val();
        //$("#draftproposalform-supervisor").val(value);'


        $.post("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["/draftproposalform.php", "id" => value).'", function(data) {

        //set value for text box
        }
]);?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'supervisor')->textInput(['readonly'=> 'true']); ?>
```

I am trying to pass the selected value to the controller so that I can query the database to look for the relevant information. Then send back that information to the view to settext.

I know how to get data from the database. I just don't know how I can pass the selected value to controller and get back a value to settext while maintaining the selected value in view.

```
public function actionDraftproposalform() {
    $model = new DraftProposalForm();

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
    {
        return $this->refresh();
    }

    else {

   $query = new Query;
   $query->select(['User.name', 'Project.title', 'Project.project_ID'])
        ->from('Project')
        ->innerJoin('Supervisor', '`Project`.`supervisor_ID` = `Supervisor`.`supervisor_ID`')
        ->innerJoin('User', '`Supervisor`.`user_ID` = `User`.`user_ID`')
        ->where(['Project.project_type_ID'=>1, 'Project.approval_ID'=>2]);

    $projectlist = $query->all();

    $fullprojectlist = ArrayHelper::map($projectlist, 'name', 'title', 'project_ID');


        return $this->render('draftproposalform', [
            'model'=>$model,
            'fullprojectlist' => $fullprojectlist]);
    }
}
```

Sorry if it's messy. Truthfully, I don't even know if passing the data back to here is the correct choice.

**Edited Codes**

View

```
<?php
        $this->registerJs(' $("#projectList").change(function() {
        var value = $("#projectList option:selected").val();
        alert(value);
        $.post(
        "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["/draftproposalform.php"]).'", 
        {id:value}, 
        function(data) {

            alert("Test");
            $("input[name=\'supervisor\']").val(data);
        }); });');
    ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'projectTitle')->dropDownList($projectlist, [
        'prompt'=>'-Choose a Course-',
        'id' => 'projectList',
        'type'=> 'POST'
        ]);
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'supervisor')->textInput(['readonly'=> 'true']); ?>
```

Controller

```
public function actionDraftproposalform() {
    $model = new DraftProposalForm();

    if(Yii::$app->request->isPost)
    {
        $id = Yii::$app->request->post("id");

        $super = DbProject::findOne(["project_ID"=>$id]);

        $supervisor = DbSupervisor::findOne(["supervisor_ID"=>$super->supervisor_ID]);

        $user = DbUser::findOne(["user_ID"=>$supervisor->user_ID]);

        //$super = DbSupervisor::findOne(["supervisor_ID"=>$id]);

    echo $user->name;

    exit;
    }


    else {


        $projectlist = ArrayHelper::map(DbProject::find()->where(['project_type_ID' => 1, 'approval_ID' => 2])->asArray()->all(), 'project_ID', 'title');

        return $this->render('draftproposalform', [
            'model'=>$model,
            'projectlist' => $projectlist]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should submit... your form

Comment: are tested your js and it's sended request to draftproposalform.php. If it is work, you should response html or json format data and in javascript success function change textbox value ;). Can you post your draftproposalform.php response action

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov Thanks for your reply. I have posted my controller code.

Comment: So now i will post answer and can u test this pls. reply if any error because maybe i'm misunderstand question or your situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you test this.
**//Controller**

```
<?
public function actionDraftproposalform() {
    $model = new DraftProposalForm();

    if(Yii::$app->request->isPost)
    {   
        $id=Yii::$app->request->post("id");
        $super=Supervisor::findOne(["supervisor_ID"=>$id]);
        if($super) echo $super->name;else echo "Not found";exit;       
    }

    else {

   $query = new Query;
   $query->select(['User.name', 'Project.title', 'Project.project_ID'])
        ->from('Project')
        ->innerJoin('Supervisor', '`Project`.`supervisor_ID` = `Supervisor`.`supervisor_ID`')
        ->innerJoin('User', '`Supervisor`.`user_ID` = `User`.`user_ID`')
        ->where(['Project.project_type_ID'=>1, 'Project.approval_ID'=>2]);

    $projectlist = $query->all();

    $fullprojectlist = ArrayHelper::map($projectlist, 'name', 'title', 'project_ID');


        return $this->render('draftproposalform', [
            'model'=>$model,
            'fullprojectlist' => $fullprojectlist]);
    }
}
```

**//view register js: put this in your view**

```
<?
$this->registerJs(' $("#projectList").change(function(){
            var value = $("#projectList option:selected").val();
            $.post(
            "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["/draftproposalform"]).'",
             { id:value },
             function(data) {
               $( "#draftproposalform-supervisor").val(data);
            }); });');
?>
```

Comment: Hi. Can you explain what this line means?  $( "input[name='supervisor']").val(data); Am i suppose to put my textbox ID in there?

Comment: this jquery selector for set text  into your textbox. Refer this : https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Hi again. I have made changes to my codes according to yours. Nothing is happening onchange. How do I test if value have been post to controller?

Comment: Check you console network panel. There should be your post request to server

Comment: Is "echo $super->name" responsible for passing the data to function(data)?

Comment: It's response to your front end javascript return like html response. function(data) data is response

Comment: Ok. I think I understand your codes now and have made necessary changes. The problem now is that my view page does not post back when a dropdownlist option is selected. Is there anything wrong with my  $.post("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["/draftproposalform.php", "id" => value).' code?

Comment: change  $("#projectList :selected").val(); to  $("#projectList option :selected").val(); . test pls and relpy what happen

Comment: I changed my answer can u test this

Comment: Hi. This line $("input[name='supervisor']").val(data) gave me syntax error, unexpected 'supervisor'. I changed it to " " instead of ' ' and the error is gone. But the result is still the same. Nothing happens,

Comment: your javscript alerted or not

Comment: yeah offcourse but u must do like this for javascript $("input[name=\'supervisor\']")

Comment: Ok. It's now $("input[name=\'supervisor\']") but still nothing. No alert also.

Comment: Can u check alert before sending post your js

Comment: There is alert before post. No alert after post.

Comment: So, our $.post not working properly. Can you check   $.post( \"//draftproposalform.php\", { id: \"3\" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert(data );
  });

Comment: I have made changes. I don't know what happened but there is no before alert and after alert.

Comment: can you check network panel from your browser, is  request sending to server, also post url  \"//draftproposalform.php\" change to \"/draftproposalform.php\" syntax error

Comment: Refer this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI and   this https://www.udemy.com/how-to-use-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Hello. I've tried checking. If i'm not mistaken, request is not sending to server.

Comment: okey, lets try to second way register javascript from view :i will update answer

Comment: I have edited my codes. When using the <? ?> tags, the code was printed out on my screen. I changed it to <script></script> and it's fine now. The result is still the same. Can you check if I have inserted your codes properly?

Comment: this is php tag change to <?php ?> on your view it's not <script> tags, okey

Comment: Yeah off course, change <script> tags into php php block open tags <?php ?> and update your question

Comment: Sorry. I changed it back already. I see that there is a request now to the server in chrome debugger but there is no alert after post.

Comment: Okey :) we achieve that. and go on server side ;

Comment: Can u check what response come from server on  network panel ? i mean content of response

Comment: I think the response in Not Found(#404): Page not found. Not sure if that's the response you're looking for.

Comment: Okey can you post that not found request url

Comment: Or actionDraftproposalform action inside of which controller

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i mean can you post class name that class which is you wrote actionDraftproposalform method. For Example SiteController

Comment: createUrl(["/SiteController.php"]) like this?

Comment: Not i mean if your controller name is SiteController and actionDraftproposalform method  inside it. U must create url like this createUrl(["site/draftproposalform.php"]) ; Also can you write your current address on browser in your project

Comment: ahh. change to  createUrl(["site/draftproposalform"])  --- without extension .php

Comment: one minute i will update answer . you can check this

Comment: It's working. ^^ $("input[name=\'supervisor\']").val(data); <- This doesn't work. $("#draftproposalform-supervisor").val(data); <- This works. Is it ok to leave it like that?

Comment: Also now u may remove alerts from  your javascript ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for helping with this issue. I'm really really grateful. ^^

Comment: Yeah, conversation  was long, But we done this ;). Can you accept my answer ;)

Comment: Accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: can you please see one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196185/unable-to-post-the-data-from-view-to-controller-in-yii2) related to it ?